# Persist iOS Tab Bar More Page

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app that has more than 5 tabs in a tab bar, so it has the standard more page as the last tab item.  The edit button lets you rearrange the tabs so that you can have the four that you want down in the bar.  This works fine.  When you rearrange the tabs, then exit the app, your new order is not persisted between restarts.  I've noticed that some of the apps that I have (from the App Store) persist the tab layout, and I am wondering if there is a standard way of doing this.

The `UITabBarController` (and its child tabs) I'm using is in a storyboard, if the implementation depends upon that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Something like this](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-uitabbarcontroller-how-to-save-user-customized-tab-order/) should be the way to go. You have to do it manually.

Just find some way to distinguish each tab (usually a title for that view controller), and keep an array of those identifiers, which you will persist to user defaults. Then when you recreate the tabs on a new app launch, use the order from that array to add them to your tab bar controller.

Comment: Strange, this seems like it would be one of the "free lunch" things that The Fruit Company gives you. Is there a special way to do this if my view controllers are being added in a storyboard vs. in code?

Comment: I have honestly not used storyboards much. But one easy way to do this is to subclass `UITabBarController` and put the rearranging logic into the `viewDidLoad` method which is called after your view is loaded from your storyboard/nib.